# how to Add some design at top after that listview with dynamic size list and then below some some design for advertisement and comment in flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Design test..."),
  ),
  body: Container(
    margin:EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top, 0, 0
  ),
  child: Column(
      children: [
        Container(//for Some Kind of design at top),
        Column(
          children: [
            ListView.builder(
                itemCount: listLength.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, int index) {
                return ListTile(title: Text("hello world")
              );
            }),
       //i want to add some design here after the list view for advertisement and comment

          ],
        ),

      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

my listview.builder() item length is dynamic so i want to expand my list view as much as it requied and when it ends i need some design just like youtube privious design where on the top video player after that video list and at the end comment part.thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve this, Refer to this code.
use the build method like this.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body : ListView(
         //Base Listview, it can be scrollable if content is large also
        children:[
          Container(
            //Sample widget you can use your own
           child:Text("Here is some design At Top")
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            //use shrinkWrap:true and physics:NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: 10, //it can be dynamic and null checks can be appield, 
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
          return Text("ListItem $index");
          },
          ),
          Container(
            //Sample widget you can use your own
            child: Text("Some Design for Ads")
          ),
          Container(
            //Sample widget you can use your own
            child: Text("Some Design for Commentes")
          )
        ]
      )
    );
  }
```

[image: Sample image for above code]

Mark answer as right if it helped !!